# mysql: Selecting multiple columns using LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have many columns which are of the form:
rp_id_1
rp_id_2
and so on.
I want to get data for these specific columns.
On the forum I see below type of query being suggested:

```
"SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='loc_tbl'
AND column_name LIKE 'rp%'"
```

However this only returns the column names and not the data. 
Output:

```
+-------------+
| column_name |
+-------------+
| rp_id_1     |
| rp_id_2     |
| rp_id_3     |
```

What am I missing? How do I get the data for all these columns instead? Thanks.

Comment: use * instead of column_name

Comment: Tried that. It returns data from the information_schema.columns table instead.

Comment: You are going to need dynamic SQL to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using dynamic MySQL.  From the MySQL command line:

```
SELECT @cols := GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_name = 'loc_tbl' AND column_name LIKE 'rp%';
SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT ", @cols, " FROM lob_tbl");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```